# Implement hashing function with collision

Tags: python, hash

For a demo project, I want to create a hashing function with a very high probability of collision. Something simple is fine since the aim of the project is NOT security - but to demonstrate hash collisions.

Can anyone help me get started with an algorithm, or a sample implementation, or just point me in the right direction?

I am doing this in Python, though maybe that should not matter.

Comment: Hash *what*? Strings, integers, floats, tuples, decimals, something entirely else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the sum of the characters in a string. It's the first hash function I was taught back when I was first learning BASIC in high school, and I ran into the collision problem right away and had to figure out how to deal with it.

```
sum(ord(c) for c in text)
```

Transpositions are easily achieved by swapping strings or even words. For more fun you could also make it case-insensitive:

```
sum(ord(c) for c in text.lower())
```

I'll even give you a sample collision for that last one: Jerry Kindall -> Dillan Kyrjer  :-)

Comment: To easily increase the chance of collision, you could calculate this sum % 10 (or some other number). :)

Comment: Jerry Kindall does not collide with Dillan Kyrjer due to case sensitivity - ord('d') != ord('D')

Comment: That's why I said it was for the *last* one. The one that's not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

One algorithm that comes to mind is hashing using the first letter of the string.

Something like

```
hash[ord(text[0]) - ord('a')] = text
```

So anything starting with the same letter will be hashed together. As you can see, that's a lot of collisions.

Another idea is to hash according to the length of the string.

```
hash[len(text)] = text
```

You can use what hayden suggests in a comment above, and cause further collisions by taking the length modulo some number. Eg.

```
hash[len(text) % 5] = text
```